# WP-CLI Process Killed

Tags: wp-cli

I have around 1200 large images which I'd like to regenerate. I'm using the WP-CLI command `wp media regenerate`. After around 61 images are generated, the terminal shows the message `Killed`.

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: If the kernel killed it there will probably be an entry in /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of WP-CLI are you using? What is `wp --version` returning you?

Seems a little bit that you may be running out of memory as this is quite a large amount of images and there doesn't seem some proper batch processing implemented in version 1 of WP-CLI. At least, that's how I'd understand this issue WP-CLI issue [Clear WP object cache periodically on media regenerate/import](https://github.com/wp-cli/media-command/pull/62) which I found in the [WP-CLI v2.0.0 Release Notes](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/2018/08/08/wp-cli-v2-0-0-release-notes/).

Is upgrading WP-CLI an option for you? If not you could also install it as a project-local dependency using Composer. Maybe you need to init a bare bone Composer project with `composer init` in your WordPress folder first.

```
$ cd /path/to/wordpress
$ composer require wp-cli/wp-cli-bundle:^2
$ vendor/bin/wp media regenerate
```

Comment: I'm using WP-CLI 2.0.1. I'm running this through Local by Flywheel, so maybe there's a limit within their pre set environment.

Comment: And you tried `$ wp media regenerate --yes` as well? What is `$ wp media regenerate --debug` returning you? Can you paste that in your question, please? Although I guess this should be filed to https://github.com/wp-cli/media-command/issues now.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. `wp media regenerate` would always get stuck at the same point with the `Killed` message, even with the `--only-missing` option.

In my case it was always after ID 571, so I tried `wp media regenerate 570`, which was the next one, and it also failed with the same message. So I deleted this image from the media library and now it's working.

By the way, adding `--debug` wouldn't give any hint about the problem. I also couldn't find any PHP logs about it.

Comment: In my case it was an image with very big dimensions (8000px in width) that caused this.